# retornar false en mi resultados Json

Tags: asp.net-core, linq, sql

tengo una consulta en LINQ y quisiera que me devolviera false cuando mi dato de entrada pin es diferente al que tengo en mi base de datos , ahora solo me regresa el Json cuando el imei es igual al de mi base de datos y me regresa true en mis variables locales , pero quisiera que me devuelva false cuando es diferente el imei ingresado al de mi base de datos

**este es mi consulta**

```
  [HttpGet("pin/{PIN}")]
        public ActionResult ugv_confirmaPIN( string pin)
        {
            Boolean reparto=false;
            Boolean preventistas=false;
            string  codigovendedor="";
            
            var data = from usuario in _context.AfcmaPersonas
                        where
                        usuario.CodUsuario.Equals(pin) // usuario.Imei.Equals(imei) &&
                       select new
                       {
                           reparto = true.ToString(),
                           usuario.DscRazonSocial,
                           preventistas = true.ToString(),
                           codigovendedor=usuario.CodUsuario.ToString()//usuario.CodClave,
                       };
            
            return Ok(data);
```

Comment: Si requieres solamente un valor boolean deberías remover el `select new` y listo

Comment: Quiero que cuando el pin que ingreso es diferente al de mi bd , me retorne false en mi json , por que cuando el pin es igual al de bd me regresa true y esta bien

Comment: Si, pero si solo necesitas eso, tienes que sacar la sentencia select de tu query, bastaría solo con el equals

Comment: Como agrego un if en mi consulta? , If en Linq

Comment: Podrías agregar la cláusula where, que necesitas hacer?

Comment: Como le dije , cuando mi imei que ingreso es igual al imei almacemado me retorne mi variables true , pero hay quiero agregar un if , cuando el imei que ingreso es diferente al que tengo almacemado me retorne en mis variables false

Comment: El código que publique como respuesta te sirve para eso, si el Imei concuerda la variable flag que esta en mi respuesta devolverá true, sino concuerda devuelve false, no necesitas hacer un if :D

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera solo que te devuelva las variables reparto y preventista true , después que te regrese datos del usuario

Comment: Entonces sólo debes asignar la query que tiene Exist y adecuarla a tus variables ya creadas, algo así `reparto = lista.Exist(/*...*/)`. La obtención de los datos del usuario, veo que ya la estás realizando ;)

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar con el método **[Exist](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.exists?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Exists_System_Predicate__0__)** asociado a las variables de tipo `List`

```
List<Persona> entities = new List<Persona>();
Persona item = new Persona
{
   Id = 1,
   Name = "Andrea"
};
entities.Add(item);

bool flag = entities.Exists(x => x.Name == "Andrea");
```

Como el método `Exist` devuelve un `boolean`, ya tienes lo que necesitas :)

Nos comentas si te sirve